# How to print AB BA AB BA BA with semaphores if i already can print AB group? in C

Tags: c, multithreading

Currently i'm using multi-thread and semaphores. I'm using semaphores and 2 threads in C, i have 2 functions in which i print A in the first thread, and in the other one that prints B. TOTAL is the variable is the time that it repeats, which is 5 pairs of letters.

This program can print AB AB AB AB sequentially

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#define TOTAL_SIZE 5

sem_t semaphore1;
sem_t semaphore2;

void printA(void *p)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore1);
        printf("A");
        fflush(NULL);

        sem_post(&semaphore2);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void printB(void *p)
{

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore2);
        printf("B");
        fflush(NULL);
        sleep(random() % 2);
        sem_post(&semaphore1);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t th1, th2;

    sem_init(&semaphore1, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&semaphore2, 0, 0);
    if (pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void *)printA, (void *)NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating thread\n");
    }
    if (pthread_create(&th2, NULL, (void *)printB, (void *)NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating thread\n");
    }
    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&semaphore1);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore2);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> AB AB AB AB AB

My question is how can i reach AB BA AB BA BA ? The total size is 5 pairs.

Comment: AB BA AB BA BA or AB BA AB BA AB?

Comment: The excercise says:
AB BA AB BA BA
The last 2 positions repeat the same pattern which is BA

Comment: Technically your thread functions have the wrong declaration. They should be declared as returning a `void *`. If you stop casting the compiler should be able to tell you that. Furthermore, any (non-function) pointer can be implicitly converted to a `void *`, which means you never need to cast `NULL`.

Comment: `fflush(NULL);`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri *"If the stream argument is NULL, fflush() flushes all open output streams."* -- [`man 3 fflush`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Comment: @oka woow I didn't know that! Thanks for the info